# How to create alarm through my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, alarm

I need my app to set the alarm. how can it be done without using Local Notifications as it will not work in IOS 3.0 . Please help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Apps pre-multiasking had to be running in the foreground all the time in order to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server, then you can implement it through Apple's Push Notifications. Set the alarm by storing an entry in the server, and when it rings, have the server send the push notification. Otherwise you cannot do this without jailbreaking the phone.

Comment: Push notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered, and can take a long time to arrive.    They're better suited to "hey this app has new content" style-notifications rather than a time-sensitive alarm feature.

Comment: The alternative will be nothing, though.

Comment: Sometimes nothing is better than something that doesn't work properly.

Comment: A local notification would definitely be the better alternative.